# i m getting garbage value in addition of two matrix objects

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class matrix
{
    public:
        int a[3][3];

        void getdata()
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
                {
                    cout<<"Enter numbers for ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]";
                    cin>>a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        void putdata()
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
                {
                    cout<<a[i][j];
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
        friend void add(matrix,matrix);
};

void add(matrix m1,matrix m2)
{ // matrix temp;
    int a,i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        a[3][3]=0;
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            //  temp.a[i][j]=x.a[i][j]+y.a[i][j];
            cout<<m1.a[i][j]+m2.a[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    // return temp;
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    matrix m1,m2,m3;
    m1.getdata();
    m2.getdata();
    add(m1,m2);
    m3.putdata();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array elements are not accessed with indexes 1 to 3 but 0 to 2.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)

for(int j=0; j<3; ++j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero based elements,

[image]

**a** is a 2-d array from 0 to 2 not 1 to 3
so following:

```
  a[3][3]=0;
   for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
            {
```

is leaving the elements related to index 0 intact...